# How to exit full screen (Chrome) in Selenium/Java other than using java.awt Robot class?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I have an application which enters full screen after login. Manually we can exit full screen by pressing 'ESCAPE' key.
I have tried pressing ESCAPE key from Selenium using Actions class:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();
```

But it's not working, the browser is still remains full screen.

I have also tried Robot class:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

This was working without headless mode but not in headless mode.

I want it to work in headless mode. Can anyone help please?

If anyone can suggest better way to key press (keyboard interaction) other than Robot class (unfortunately, Actions class is also not working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.manage().window().maximize();` exits full screen mode.

Comment: Yes this will exit full screen mode but is there any way to press Escape key (Except Robot class)?